# Forcing footnotes to appear on the next page

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, footmisc

I need a way to make some footnotes appear on page 2n+1 when the text that they're "attached" to occurs on page 2n.  Is there something like a `\newpage` command that I could use in the middle of paragraph-style footnote (`para` option in `footmisc`) that would force the remaining footnotes for page 2n onto page 2n+1?

Given that this is the opposite problem to what worries most people, it's probably necessary to understand what I'm working on, to see why I need this.

I'm preparing a dual-language book (documenting a Native American language).  The layout of the book is to be:

1. Upper portion even-numbered page: Kiowa
2. Upper portion odd-numbered page: English
3. Lower portion both pages: word-by-word translation

A nice way to do this seems to be with `\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc}` together with the command:

```
\newcommand{\z}[2]{#1\symbolfootnote[0]{#1 \textit{#2}}}
```

(`\symbolfootnote[0]` gives you a footnote without a footnotemark; see code below.  So, `\z` adds a Kiowa word to the main text and, at the same time, adds the word together with its English translation at the bottom of the page.)

For this to work well, I want to split the footnotes (the Kiowa-English pairs) evenly between the even- and odd-numbered pages.  But, of course, latex and `footmisc` want all the footnotes on the even-numbered page, where I put the Kiowa text, and next to none on the odd-numbered page, where I put the idiomatic English translation.

Hence, the search for a `\newpage`-like command for use in the middle of paragraph-style footnote to force the remaining footnotes for page 2n onto page 2n+1.

Below, I've put in an example based on some text I nabbed from wikipedia (not a very attentive translation, apologies to any Germans).  Pages 2-3 show the problem.  Pages 4-5 show what I'm actually aiming for (though the code I use to get there is messy, involving much copying, pasting, and manual fiddling).

(1. I'm aware that I'm creating a memory-taxing document by putting in so many footnotes. I'm open to suggestions about other ways of doing this.  2. I'm also open to alternatives to the `\z` command. 3. I've used a parallel text package on a different project, but it won't work here, because it doesn't allow footnotes.)

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}{.5em}{0em}{}{}
\makeatother

\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\z}[2]{#1\symbolfootnote[0]{#1 \textit{#2}}}

\begin{document}

WRONG VERSION ON PAGES 2, 3

RIGHT VERSION ON PAGES 4, 5

\newpage

\z{Der}{the} \z{Englisch-Spanische}{Anglo-Spanish} \z{Krieg}{war} \z{war}{was} \z{ein}{a} \z{milit\"arischer}{military} \z{Konflikt}{confict} \z{zwischen}{between} \z{dem}{the} \z{K\"onigreich}{kingdom} \z{Gro\ss britannien}{Great Britain} \z{und}{and} \z{dem}{the} \z{K\"onigreich}{kingdom} \z{Spanien}{Spain}. \z{Obwohl}{although} \z{die}{the} \z{ersten}{first} \z{Kampfhandlungen}{combat} \z{bereits}{already} \z{im}{in the} \z{Sommer}{summer} \z{1726}{1726} \z{in}{in} \z{der}{the} \z{Karibik}{Caribbean} \z{begannen,}{began} \z{wird}{was} \z{allgemein}{generally} \z{erst}{first} \z{mit}{with} \z{dem}{the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{der}{of the} \z{offenen}{open} \z{Konfrontation}{confrontation} \z{in}{in} \z{Europa}{Europe} \z{am}{on the} \z{11.}{eleventh}\ \z{Februar}{February} \z{1727}{1727} \z{von}{of} \z{einem}{a} \z{Krieg}{war} \z{gesprochen}{discussed}. \z{Der}{the} \z{formell}{formally} \z{unerkl\"arte}{undeclare} \z{Kriegszustand}{state of war} \z{zwischen}{between} \z{beiden}{both} \z{Staaten}{states} \z{bildete}{rose} \z{den}{to a} \z{H\"ohepunkt}{climax} \z{einer}{of a} \z{gesamteurop\"aischen}{pan-European} \z{Krise}{crisis}, \z{auf deren einer Seite}{on one side of which} \z{die}{the} \z{Herrenhausener}{Herrenhaus} \z{Allianz}{Alliance} \z{und}{and} \z{auf deren anderer}{on the other} \z{die}{the} \z{Partner}{Partners} \z{des}{of the } \z{Wiener}{Vienna} \z{Vertrages}{Treaty} \z{standen}{stood}. \z{Der}{the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{eines}{of a} \z{allgemeinen}{general} \z{Krieges}{war} \z{konnte}{could} \z{jedoch}{yet} \z{diplomatisch}{diplomatically} \z{verhindert}{prevented} \z{werden}{be}. \z{Im Wesentlichen}{substantially} \z{beschr\"ankten sich}{were restricted} \z{die}{the} \z{Kampfhandlungen}{combat} \z{auf}{to} \z{maritime}{maritime} \z{Operationen}{operations} \z{in}{in} \z{der}{the} \z{Karibik,}{Caribbean} \z{ohne}{without} \z{dass}{that} \z{es}{it} \z{dabei}{thereby} \z{zu}{to} \z{gr\"o{\ss}eren}{greater} \z{Seeschlachten}{sea battles} \z{gekommen w\"are}{came}. \z{In}{in} \z{Europa}{Europe} \z{war}{was} \z{die}{the} \z{erfolglose}{unsuccessful} \z{Belagerung}{siege} \z{des}{of the} \z{britischen}{British} \z{St\"utzpunktes}{base} \z{Gibraltar}{Gibraltar} \z{die}{the} \z{einzige}{only} \z{nennenswerte}{notable} \z{Auseinandersetzung}{confrontation}. \z{Der}{the} \z{englisch-spanische}{Anglo-Spanish} \z{Konflikt}{Conflict} \z{endete}{ended} \z{formell}{formally} \z{am}{on the} \z{9.}{ninth}\ \z{November}{November} \z{1729}{1729} \z{mit}{with} \z{dem}{the} \z{Abschluss}{signing} \z{des}{of the} \z{Vertrages}{Treaty} \z{von}{of} \z{Sevilla}{Seville} \z{und}{and} \z{der}{the} \z{Wiederherstellung}{restoration} \z{des}{of the} \z{Status}{status} \z{quo ante}{quo ante}. \z{Die}{The} \z{grunds\"atzlichen}{fundamental} \z{Differenzen}{differences} \z{beider}{of both} \z{Staaten}{states} \z{wurden}{were} \z{jedoch}{nonetheless} \z{nicht}{not} \z{beseitigt}{eliminated}, \z{was}{which} \z{kaum}{barely} \z{zehn}{ten} \z{Jahre}{years} \z{sp\"ater}{later} \z{zum}{to the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{eines}{of a} \z{weiteren}{further} \z{Krieges}{war} \z{f\"uhrte}{led}.

The Anglo-Spanish War was a military conflict between the kingdoms of Great Britain and Spain.  Although combat had already been met in the Caribbean in the summer of 1726, war was not openly spoken of until the outbreak of open confrontation in Europa,  on until 11 February 1727.  The formally undeclared state of war between the two states reached a climax in a pan-European crisis, pitting the members of the Herrenhauser Alliance against the partners of the Vienna Treaty.  The outbreak of full-scale war could nonetheless have been avoided by diplomatic means.  For the most part, combat was confined to maritime operations in the Caribbean, though without leading to any larger sea battles.  The only noteworthy conflict in Europe was the unsuccessful seige of the British base of Gibraltar.  The Anglo-Spanish conflict was formally ended on 9 November 1729 with the signing of the Treaty of Seville and the restoration of the status quo ante.  The fundamental differences between the two sides remained unresolved, however, which was to lead and further outbreak of war, less than ten years later.

\newpage

\z{Der}{the} \z{Englisch-Spanische}{Anglo-Spanish} \z{Krieg}{war} \z{war}{was} \z{ein}{a} \z{milit\"arischer}{military} \z{Konflikt}{confict} \z{zwischen}{between} \z{dem}{the} \z{K\"onigreich}{kingdom} \z{Gro\ss britannien}{Great Britain} \z{und}{and} \z{dem}{the} \z{K\"onigreich}{kingdom} \z{Spanien}{Spain}. \z{Obwohl}{although} \z{die}{the} \z{ersten}{first} \z{Kampfhandlungen}{combat} \z{bereits}{already} \z{im}{in the} \z{Sommer}{summer} \z{1726}{1726} \z{in}{in} \z{der}{the} \z{Karibik}{Caribbean} \z{begannen,}{began} \z{wird}{was} \z{allgemein}{generally} \z{erst}{first} \z{mit}{with} \z{dem}{the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{der}{of the} \z{offenen}{open} \z{Konfrontation}{confrontation} \z{in}{in} \z{Europa}{Europe} \z{am}{on the} \z{11.}{eleventh}\ \z{Februar}{February} \z{1727}{1727} \z{von}{of} \z{einem}{a} \z{Krieg}{war} \z{gesprochen}{discussed}. \z{Der}{the} \z{formell}{formally} \z{unerkl\"arte}{undeclare} \z{Kriegszustand}{state of war} \z{zwischen}{between} \z{beiden}{both} \z{Staaten}{states} \z{bildete}{rose} \z{den}{to a} \z{H\"ohepunkt}{climax} \z{einer}{of a} \z{gesamteurop\"aischen}{pan-European} \z{Krise}{crisis}, \z{auf deren einer Seite}{on one side of which} \z{die}{the} \z{Herrenhausener}{Herrenhaus} \z{Allianz}{Alliance} \z{und}{and} \z{auf deren anderer}{on the other} \z{die}{the} \z{Partner}{Partners} \z{des}{of the } \z{Wiener}{Vienna} \z{Vertrages}{Treaty} \z{standen}{stood}. \z{Der}{the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{eines}{of a} \z{allgemeinen}{general} \z{Krieges}{war} \z{konnte}{could} \z{jedoch}{yet}  
\renewcommand{\z}[2]{#1}
\z{diplomatisch}{diplomatically} \z{verhindert}{prevented} \z{werden}{be}. \z{Im Wesentlichen}{substantially} \z{beschr\"ankten sich}{were restricted} \z{die}{the} \z{Kampfhandlungen}{combat} \z{auf}{to} \z{maritime}{maritime} \z{Operationen}{operations} \z{in}{in} \z{der}{the} \z{Karibik,}{Caribbean} \z{ohne}{without} \z{dass}{that} \z{es}{it} \z{dabei}{thereby} \z{zu}{to} \z{gr\"o{\ss}eren}{greater} \z{Seeschlachten}{sea battles} \z{gekommen w\"are}{came}. \z{In}{in} \z{Europa}{Europe} \z{war}{was} \z{die}{the} \z{erfolglose}{unsuccessful} \z{Belagerung}{siege} \z{des}{of the} \z{britischen}{British} \z{St\"utzpunktes}{base} \z{Gibraltar}{Gibraltar} \z{die}{the} \z{einzige}{only} \z{nennenswerte}{notable} \z{Auseinandersetzung}{confrontation}. \z{Der}{the} \z{englisch-spanische}{Anglo-Spanish} \z{Konflikt}{Conflict} \z{endete}{ended} \z{formell}{formally} \z{am}{on the} \z{9.}{ninth}\ \z{November}{November} \z{1729}{1729} \z{mit}{with} \z{dem}{the} \z{Abschluss}{signing} \z{des}{of the} \z{Vertrages}{Treaty} \z{von}{of} \z{Sevilla}{Seville} \z{und}{and} \z{der}{the} \z{Wiederherstellung}{restoration} \z{des}{of the} \z{Status}{status} \z{quo ante}{quo ante}. \z{Die}{The} \z{grunds\"atzlichen}{fundamental} \z{Differenzen}{differences} \z{beider}{of both} \z{Staaten}{states} \z{wurden}{were} \z{jedoch}{nonetheless} \z{nicht}{not} \z{beseitigt}{eliminated}, \z{was}{which} \z{kaum}{barely} \z{zehn}{ten} \z{Jahre}{years} \z{sp\"ater}{later} \z{zum}{to the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{eines}{of a} \z{weiteren}{further} \z{Krieges}{war} \z{f\"uhrte}{led}.
\newpage
{\it The Anglo-Spanish War was a military conflict between the kingdoms of Great Britain and Spain.  Although combat had already been met in the Caribbean in the summer of 1726, war was not openly spoken of until the outbreak of open confrontation in Europa,  on until 11 February 1727.  The formally undeclared state of war between the two states reached a climax in a pan-European crisis, pitting the members of the Herrenhauser Alliance against the partners of the Vienna Treaty.  The outbreak of full-scale war could nonetheless have been avoided by diplomatic means.  For the most part, combat was confined to maritime operations in the Caribbean, though without leading to any larger sea battles.  The only noteworthy conflict in Europe was the unsuccessful seige of the British base of Gibraltar.  The Anglo-Spanish conflict was formally ended on 9 November 1729 with the signing of the Treaty of Seville and the restoration of the status quo ante.  The fundamental differences between the two sides remained unresolved, however, which was to lead and further outbreak of war, less than ten years later.}
\renewcommand{\z}[2]{\symbolfootnote[0]{#1 \textit{#2}}}
\z{diplomatisch}{diplomatically} \z{verhindert}{prevented} \z{werden}{be} \z{Im Wesentlichen}{substantially} \z{beschr\"ankten sich}{were restricted} \z{die}{the} \z{Kampfhandlungen}{combat} \z{auf}{to} \z{maritime}{maritime} \z{Operationen}{operations} \z{in}{in} \z{der}{the} \z{Karibik}{Caribbean} \z{ohne}{without} \z{dass}{that} \z{es}{it} \z{dabei}{thereby} \z{zu}{to} \z{gr\"o{\ss}eren}{greater} \z{Seeschlachten}{sea battles} \z{gekommen w\"are}{came} \z{In}{in} \z{Europa}{Europe} \z{war}{was} \z{die}{the} \z{erfolglose}{unsuccessful} \z{Belagerung}{siege} \z{des}{of the} \z{britischen}{British} \z{St\"utzpunktes}{base} \z{Gibraltar}{Gibraltar} \z{die}{the} \z{einzige}{only} \z{nennenswerte}{notable} \z{Auseinandersetzung}{confrontation} \z{Der}{the} \z{englisch-spanische}{Anglo-Spanish} \z{Konflikt}{Conflict} \z{endete}{ended} \z{formell}{formally} \z{am}{on the} \z{9.}{ninth}\ \z{November}{November} \z{1729}{1729} \z{mit}{with} \z{dem}{the} \z{Abschluss}{signing} \z{des}{of the} \z{Vertrages}{Treaty} \z{von}{of} \z{Sevilla}{Seville} \z{und}{and} \z{der}{the} \z{Wiederherstellung}{restoration} \z{des}{of the} \z{Status}{status} \z{quo ante}{quo ante} \z{Die}{The} \z{grunds\"atzlichen}{fundamental} \z{Differenzen}{differences} \z{beider}{of both} \z{Staaten}{states} \z{wurden}{were} \z{jedoch}{nonetheless} \z{nicht}{not} \z{beseitigt}{eliminated} \z{was}{which} \z{kaum}{barely} \z{zehn}{ten} \z{Jahre}{years} \z{sp\"ater}{later} \z{zum}{to the} \z{Ausbruch}{outbreak} \z{eines}{of a} \z{weiteren}{further} \z{Krieges}{war} \z{f\"uhrte}{led}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

It just occurred to me to mix `footmisc.sty` with `endnotes.sty`.  Here's a solution, good enough for my purposes.  It just involves changing half of the footnotes on page 2n to endnotes and then inserting `\theendnotes` on page 2n+1.  You then toggle to footnotes again for the first half of page 2n+2, then to endnotes, and so on.

I haven't made any other alterations to the display, so as not to disguise anything.  For my dual-text book, I'll kill the **Notes** heading, of course (don't want that cluttering up every 2n+1th page); and, as previously mentioned, the footnotes will lack footnotemarks, so it doesn't matter `1` occurs twice on the same page, for the footnote and the "endnote".

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[para,norule,hang]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\underline{This sentence has a footnote on the same page}\footnote{\underline{See!  I'm on the same page}} 
{\it This sentence has a footnote on the next page}\endnote{\it See! I'm on the next page}

\newpage

{I don't have any footnote}
\vfill
\theendnotes

\newpage

\underline{\underline{This sentence has a footnote on the same    page}}\footnote{\underline{\underline{See!  I'm on the same page}}} 
{\bf This sentence has a footnote on the next page}\endnote{\bf See! I'm on the next page}
\newpage

{I don't have any footnote again}
\vfill
\theendnotes

\end{document}
```