# \footnotetex one page after \footnotemark for title page

Tags: footnotes

The guidelines for title pages at my department prescribe that acknowledgements should be placed on the page following the title page. The reason for this seems to be that the title page may be removed to allow papers to compete anonymously, while preserving any information relevant to the thesis (like acknowledgements).

Until now, I used to redefine `\thefootnote` to look like a symbol of my choice, then reset everything afterwards. Thus, the following code for my name and acknowledgements:

```
{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\setcounter{footnote}{1}
\textbf{My name}\footnote{
The author is indebted to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Estne, quaeso, inquam, sitienti in bibendo voluptas? Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Hoc non est positum in nostra actione. Quare obscurentur etiam haec, quae secundum naturam esse dicimus, in vita beata; Sed id ne cogitari quidem potest quale sit, ut non repugnet ipsum sibi. Hoc tu nunc in illo probas. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. An quod ita callida est, ut optime possit architectari voluptates?
}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
```

Now that acknowledgements are required to go on the subsequent page, I am wondering whether there is a simple extension to this piece of code that would achieve this.

EDIT: I am aware of e.g. [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58534/forcing-footnotes-to-appear-on-the-next-page), but I want to change footnote behavior at one instance only, not for the entire document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` combo with a `\clearpage` in between.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  {\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\setcounter{footnote}{1}
\textbf{My name}\footnotemark

Some text here
\clearpage

\footnotetext{%
The author is indebted to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Estne, quaeso, inquam, sitienti in bibendo voluptas? Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Hoc non est positum in nostra actione. Quare obscurentur etiam haec, quae secundum naturam esse dicimus, in vita beata; Sed id ne cogitari quidem potest quale sit, ut non repugnet ipsum sibi. Hoc tu nunc in illo probas. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. An quod ita callida est, ut optime possit architectari voluptates?
}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know that was possible even, thank you very much!